# How to merge two pd.Series without duplicates, keeping the alternating order

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, concatenation

### Question

- I have 2 `pd.Series` variables, which I would like to merge without duplicates, keeping the `buy` - `sell` alternating order.
- These 2 pd.Series are my transaction histories on trading Google and Apple stocks.
- Since I am buying a stock with all my money, I can hold just one stock at any point of time. Thus, there cannot be two buys in a consecutive order. This is the same on sell, as well. I sell all the amount of a single stock (AAPL or GOOG) at one shot.
- Can I do this task without using for loop?
- The code example in more detail is provided below.

### Code Example

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

########################
# Google stock trading #
########################
google_index_list = [datetime(2020,1,2,2), datetime(2020,1,2,12), datetime(2020,1,3,7), datetime(2020,1,4,2)]
google_transaction_list = ['buy', 'sell', 'buy', 'sell']
google_trade_series = pd.Series(data=google_transaction_list, index=google_index_list)

#######################
# Apple stock trading #
#######################
apple_index_list = [datetime(2020,1,2,12), datetime(2020,1,2,14), datetime(2020,1,4,3), datetime(2020,1,4,9)]
apple_transaction_list = ['buy', 'sell', 'buy', 'sell']
apple_trade_series = pd.Series(data=apple_transaction_list, index=apple_index_list)

google_trade_series
>> 2020-01-02 02:00:00     buy
   2020-01-02 12:00:00    sell
   2020-01-03 07:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 02:00:00    sell

apple_trade_series
>> 2020-01-02 12:00:00     buy
   2020-01-02 14:00:00    sell
   2020-01-04 03:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 09:00:00    sell

############################
# Merging two trade_series #
############################
merged_trade_series = pd.concat([google_trade_series, apple_trade_series])
merged_trade_series.sort_index(inplace=True)

merged_trade_series
>> 2020-01-02 02:00:00     buy
   2020-01-02 12:00:00    sell
   2020-01-02 12:00:00     buy
   2020-01-02 14:00:00    sell
   2020-01-03 07:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 02:00:00    sell
   2020-01-04 03:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 09:00:00    sell
```

There are 2 problems in the variable `merged_trade_series`.

- 1st problem: We have 2 rows with the same datetime `2001-01-02 12:00:00`. Since I already had the stock Google, which I bought at 2020-01-02 02:00:00, the action that I should take is 'sell'. So the 'buy' row should be deleted.
- 2nd problem: I didn't buy the stock at 2001-01-02 12:00:00, I don't have any stock to sell at `2001-01-02 14:00:00`. So this 'sell' row should be deleted as well.

As a result, the desired merged_trade_series is as follows:

```py
desired_trade_series
>> 2020-01-02 02:00:00     buy
   2020-01-02 12:00:00    sell
   2020-01-03 07:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 02:00:00    sell
   2020-01-04 03:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 09:00:00    sell
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, two things need to be deleted.

1. **duplicated indices**: `pd.Series.index.duplicated()` can filter out duplicated datetime indices
2. **consecutive buys & sells**: `pd.Series[pd.Series != pd.Series.shift(1)` can delete rows with the consecutive values.

My solution to handle the problem in my question is as follows:

```py
# getting rid of consecutive buys or sells, except for the first one. 
no_consecutive_series = merged_trade_series[merged_trade_series != merged_trade_series.shift(1)]

no_consecutive_series
>> 2020-01-02 02:00:00     buy
   2020-01-02 12:00:00    sell
   2020-01-02 12:00:00     buy
   2020-01-02 14:00:00    sell
   2020-01-03 07:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 02:00:00    sell
   2020-01-04 03:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 09:00:00    sell

# getting rid of duplicated indices
no_duplicate_series = no_consecutive_series[~no_consecutive_series.index.duplicated()]

no_duplicate_series
>> 2020-01-02 02:00:00     buy
   2020-01-02 12:00:00    sell
   2020-01-02 14:00:00    sell
   2020-01-03 07:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 02:00:00    sell
   2020-01-04 03:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 09:00:00    sell

# deleting the consecutive buys or sells, after deleting the duplicated indices
final_series = no_duplicate_series[no_duplicate_series!= no_duplicate_series.shift(1)]

final_series
>> 2020-01-02 02:00:00     buy
   2020-01-02 12:00:00    sell
   2020-01-03 07:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 02:00:00    sell
   2020-01-04 03:00:00     buy
   2020-01-04 09:00:00    sell
```

By doing this way,  it does not matter whether the `merged_trade_serise` is...

```py
merged_trade_series = pd.concat([google_trade_series, apple_trade_series])
```

or

```py
merged_trade_series = pd.concat([apple_trade_series, google_trade_series])
```